# Why is console logging 2 different outputs of element when refreshing page?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console

The console in Chrome DevTools is giving me 2 different outputs of a `console.log` at random when I refresh the page.

Code:

```
function createItem(name, parent, liClasses, btnClasses, iClasses) {
    const div = document.getElementById(parent);
    const li = createLi(name, liClasses);
    const btn = createButton(btnClasses);
    const i = createIcon(iClasses);

    btn.appendChild(i);
    li.appendChild(btn);
    div.appendChild(li);

    return div;
}

console.log(
    createItem('Coffee', 'main', 'li classes', 'btn classes', 'i classes')
);
```

Chrome DevTools output 1:

[image: Output 1]

Output 2:

[image: Output 2]

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible that the `console` is logging the output of the function `createItem()` at different stages of its execution ***due to the asynchronous nature of some of the operations within the function***.

To ensure consistent logging output, you can wrap the function call in a `setTimeout()` function with a delay of `0 milliseconds`:

```js
setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(createItem('Coffee', 'main', 'li classes', 'btn classes', 'i classes'));
}, 0);
```

This will ensure that the `console.log()` statement is executed after the function has completed its execution and all asynchronous operations have finished.

Comment: Makes sense. Unfortunately I'm no longer able to reproduce output 1 even before adding the setTimeout function. Perhaps when I return to the coworking space where I first noticed this. I'll accept the answer now and try to verify soon. Thanks.

Comment: Sure @dannypernik. All the best! Cheers.